# How to create my own preference screen?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Please have a look on the image:
[image]

There is an item rounded with red color on the right pane. This is a `PreferenceScreen` item. I need to show another my own view after clicking on this item. See next screen please:

[image]

Comment: The point behind the preference screen system is to present a consistent UX. You are welcome to create your own `Preference` subclasses (typically extending `DialogPreference`), for types of data that do not fit the existing preference types. Or, you can put a preference header in the left pane that launches a totally different activity (taking over the whole screen) via an `<intent>` child element. However, if you do not want to present a consistent preference UX, do not use the preference screens at all, and simply design your own activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make really minimal subclasses of the neccessary `Preference` classes where you set your own layout via `setLayoutResource()` in the constructor and bind anything you need to pass in with xml parameters by overriding the `onBindView(View)` method.

These can then be used inside a `PreferenceScreen` in xml by using the fully qualified `<com.mypackage.mypreference/>` tag

If you find yourself making a lot of different views you might want to reconsider, because although settings can reasonably stand some theming. It probably shouldn't get too "widget-y".